# Wordpress Authentication

Tags: wordpress

I am currently coding a WordPress Plugin. The plugin basically, adds a custom login form to any post or page using short code and allows user to login a custom page.

However, I have been reading the WordPress codex and on forums about user authentication using the WordPress Authentication functions or using a custom coded authentication script.

So my question is which would be the best option to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use WordPress authentication. It would be fastest and better then custom authentication solution.

Comment: Could I also use the WordPress authentication to enable external users to login also?

Comment: What do you mean with 'external users'? Anonymous, users registered by another platform and stored in another db...